# Turning abstract class without fields to interface (Java, Sonar rule s1610)

Tags: java, interface, abstract-class

I refer to [this rule](https://rules.sonarsource.com/java/RSPEC-1610):

> With Java 8's "default method" feature, any abstract class without direct or inherited field should be converted into an interface.

- In my perception default + private methods in Java8+ interfaces is a
  *pure compromise* JDK designers took in order to solve a dilemma they faced: they had to introduce new methods (for ex. Map interface)
  without breaking old code that used those interfaces (backward
  compatibility).
- In practice JDK designers introduced *implementation inheritance* in places
  where *interface inheritance* existed, so potentially they
  increased coupling and brittleness of our existing and future code.
- In my perception introduced *implementation inheritance* now diminishes cool nature of interfaces - the *multiple inheritance*.
- I understand why *"abstract classes without fields"* is mentioned in Sonar rule. By this the authors of the rule do lessen brittleness (but don't eliminate the fact of implementation inheritance). Compare to problems of Scala traits that do permit fields (new Java interfaces look more and more like Scala's traits) - Scala lang designers tried to solve those problems with things like trait linearization, lazy vals, etc.
- I'm avoiding arguments like "it is in JDK so it is a pattern", let us speak more at the conceptual level here.
- **Question**: Could anyone explain me why Sonar promotes this, IMHO, flawed rule?
  What do we gain by such a rule? What benefit/use case am I missing here?

Thanks.

Comment: Interesting the rule doesn't address protected methods of abstract class (which couldn't be specified in an interface where everything is implicitly public) - perhaps it addresses this without saying as much.

Comment: 2023-06-22 update: sonarcloud.io has deprecated this rule and removed it from default quality profiles.

Answer (score 1):

I don't necessarily agree with the rule, but I see where it's coming from.

The thing is that you don't really lose anything in this case. The only time you'd run into problems with regard to multiple inheritance would be if you implemented several interfaces containing methods with the same signature and different implementations.

However, this is forbidden by Java (you'd need to provide your own implementation of that method), so there is no danger in doing so.

In general, interfaces are more versatile than classes, so it makes sense to use them if possible.

As a counter point, the interface `default` feature was introduced to allow adding methods to existing interfaces without breaking existing code, but that's not the case here.

Comment: i'm aware of scala's traits and problems they bring, java8+ interfaces look more like traits now... - hence my question about this Sonar rule, i came across today...

Comment: You do lose a few things. One is that a `default` method cannot be `final`. Another is that an abstract class can have a constructor which does something, even if there is no state to initialise. Also, an abstract class can override a concrete method from a superclass (e.g. `toString` or `hashCode`) to make that method `abstract`, forcing subclasses to provide a new implementation rather than inherit the implementation from the superclass. Even if the abstract class doesn't currently do any of these things, converting it to an interface closes off the option in future.

Comment: @kaya3 All true, with different degrees of relevance. The constructor point is a good one. `final` is true and I'd like to use it more often, but it prevents mocking classes with Mockito so I find myself hardly ever doing it. Overriding an existing method with an `abstract` class does work, but I'd consider it a code smell since it disables existing functionality - in which case you should rethink your existing hierarchy, or for JDK lib functions as you mention, why you would force devs to provide your own implementation rather than using a working one..

Comment: Both of you give interesting and valid comments. There is also 1 more observation: what does this sonar rule teaches the novice? That having implementation in interface is very ok :) . Java novice would push this principle further after seening such sonar practices - novice might start to use defaults even in cases when abstract class was never meant in his code - just because it was adviced on other occasion... Sonar here obfuscates the fact that depending on pure interface (<jdk8) is less coupling than depending on interface with default methods...

Comment: @daniu The use-case for making existing methods abstract is when the prior implementation isn't "working" for the purpose of the class; say you have a hierarchy of classes designed to be used as HashMap keys, such that the behaviour of `Object.equals` and `Object.hashCode` would be wrong because you need those to be computed by value rather than by identity - but the abstract base class can't implement those methods since they depend on the fields of the subclasses. In that case, making `equals` and `hashCode` abstract is good because the prior implementation is wrong for the subclasses.

Comment: @kaya3 Yes I know what you were getting at. But enforcing this with an additional class in the hierarchy is an anti-pattern to me. And in the end, either the resulting behavior is incorrect, and the methods need to be overridden anyway; or it is not, which would make overriding them unecessary.

Comment: It's not necessarily an additional class in the hierarchy, if you were already writing an abstract base class anyway - and yes, you're overriding those methods in the subclasses either way, but since subclasses *must* do so then it's useful for the compiler to check that they do.

Comment: @Max Sonarqube is not an educational tool. Its rules are meant to point you to look at something that might be correct for your specific case (then you can mark it as "will not fix" with an explanation), and that's perfectly fine (although probably not for the novice to decide ;)).

Comment: @daniu. Yes, if you're not working in the environment where sonar is taken as an authoritative reference ... By the moment i can't figure out any relevant use case where this rule is an adequate improvement, hence my search for opinions... Btw, thanks